# Way to catch all type of rised signals in DB2 SQL-PL via a declare handler

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, sql-pl

I want to treat all types of generated signals in my code. I know how to catch a specific one with a Declare Handler, however I would like all of them.

For example, here I catch the 72822 signal.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '72822'
  BEGIN
    IF ( var = 'OK' )
      RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '72623' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Got SQLSTATE 72822';
    ELSE
      RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '72319' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = var;
  END;
```

I will call a stored procedure that I do not know the code, and I have to be able to deal with all possible signals (for example insert the signal code in a table.)

I would like something like

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR ALL
```

Answer (score 3):

That would be `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING`, I think.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html

Comment: The answer above is a way to do this.  I would recommend, however, that you separate the handlers (depending on the application).

You would want an exit handler for the exceptions, but you will probably want a continue handler for the warnings. 

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING

This is helpful because you do not always want to exit when there is simply a conversion.

Comment: @mustaccio It is just a question, are you interested to develop an open source framework for unit test in SQL PL? contact me if you are interested: angoca at yahoo dot com

Comment: Agree with @jgriffin. Continue handlers can be useful for exceptions as well, because you may want to recover from certain types of errors (e.g. create a table if it didn't exist).